# How to interpret a final tagless DSL with ZIO?

Tags: scala, dsl, module-pattern, zio

I have a final tagless DSL to build simple math expressions:

```scala
trait Entity[F[_]] {
  def empty: F[Int]
  def int(value: Int): F[Int]
}

trait Operation[F[_]] {
  def add(a: F[Int], b: F[Int]): F[Int]
}
```

I wanted to implement a ZIO interpreter. Based on the `module-pattern` [guide](https://zio.dev/docs/howto/howto_use_layers), a possible implementation could look as follows:

```scala
type Entity = Has[Entity[UIO]]

object Entity {
  val test: ULayer[Entity] =
    ZLayer.succeed {
      new Entity[UIO] {
        override def empty: UIO[Int] =
          ZIO.succeed(0)

        override def int(value: Int): UIO[Int] =
          ZIO.succeed(value)
      }
    }

  def empty: URIO[Entity, Int] =
    ZIO.accessM(_.get.empty)

  def int(value: Int): URIO[Entity, Int] =
    ZIO.accessM(_.get.int(value))
}

type Operation = Has[Operation[UIO]]

object Operation {
  val test: ULayer[Operation] =
    ZLayer.succeed {
      new Operation[UIO] {
        override def add(a: UIO[Int], b: UIO[Int]): UIO[Int] =
          ZIO.tupled(a, b).map { case (x, y) => x + y }
      }
    }

  def add(a: UIO[Int], b: UIO[Int]): URIO[Operation, Int] =
    ZIO.accessM(_.get.add(a, b))
}
```

When building expressions with this implementation, one has to call `provideLayer` repeatedly like this:

```scala
Operation.subtract(
  Entity.empty.provideLayer(Entity.test),
  Entity.int(10).provideLayer(Entity.test)
).provideLayer(Operation.test)
```

That looks more like an anti-pattern. What would be the most idiomatic or the most ZIO way to interpret DSLs?

Comment: `def add(a: UIO[Int], b: UIO[Int]): UIO[Int]` is a bit odd. Why not `add(a: Int, b: Int): UIO[Int])`?

Comment: or maybe `add(a: Term[Int], b: Term[Int]): Term[Int]` for some kind of `Term` to encode your math expressions? Where does ZIO come into that? `ZIO` describes effects (that you can then run and compose, but not look inside anymore to understand what they do).

Comment: Unlike the example, the `Service` traits are defined somewhere else, and I only use ZIO to implement them. Meaning they cannot be changed. For clarification, they have the signature `def int(value: Int): F[Int]` and `def add(a: F[Int], b: F[Int]): F[Int]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting back to this question with a better understanding of ZIO I have found a solution. It is a workaround and not in the spirit of ZIO, nevertheless, I thought it might be worth sharing.

I updated the Operation implementation of ZIO:

```
type Operation = Has[Service[URIO[Entity, *]]]

object Operation {
  val live: ULayer[Operation] =
    ZLayer.succeed {
      new Service[URIO[Entity, *]] {
        override def add(a: URIO[Entity, Int])(b: URIO[Entity, Int]): URIO[Entity, Int] =
          a.zip(b).map { case (x, y) => x + y }
      }
    }
}

def add(a: URIO[Entity, Int])(b: URIO[Entity, Int]): URIO[Entity with Operation, Int] =
  ZIO.accessM(_.get[Service[URIO[Entity, *]]].add(a)(b))
```

This way Entity and Operation can be combined like this:

```
operation.add(entity.int(5))(entity.int(37))
```

Answer (score 0):

It not really clear from the question what you are trying to achieve but let me try to answer.

1. ZIO's `R` parameter is not directly related to building DSLs.
   Once you build your DSL, `R` can potentially help you pass it to your computation ergonomically (but probably not).
2. DSL is not a precise term but still it's unlikely that `ZIO` would help you building it.
   DSLs are usually based on plain introspectable datatypes (so-called initial encoding) or abstract datatypes with lots of `F`s (final encoding). `ZIO` datatype is neither abstract nor introspectable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I simplified the use case to make it easier to understand, but maybe some context information is necessary. I have a finally tagless DSL I want to "interpret" using ZIO. The DSL has the signature `def int(value: Int): F[Int]` and `def add(a: F[Int], b: F[Int]): F[Int]`.

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope that makes it more clear.